# JavaScript nested loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I'm trying to change the values in a specific position of a multi-dimensional array (three levels) using nested loops, but I can't seem to get it to work as desired.

As you'll see in the code below, my array begins with three arrays and each of these three arrays have two arrays. What I'm trying to do is to change the second value of each of the "deeper" arrays, but the new value will be different depending on which of the middle-level arrays holds that deeper array.

This is how the array begins:

```
[[['A','X'],['B','X']],
 [['C','X'],['D','X']],
 [['E','X'],['F','X']]]
```

I'm trying to change 'X'. The first two exes are in the same array of arrays, so they'll get the same output - and so on. This is the desired result:

```
[[['A','Output 1'],['B','Output 1']],
 [['C','Output 2'],['D','Output 2']],
 [['E','Output 3'],['F','Output 3']]]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var myArray = [
  [
    ['A', 'X'],
    ['B', 'X']
  ],
  [
    ['C', 'X'],
    ['D', 'X']
  ],
  [
    ['E', 'X'],
    ['F', 'X']
  ]
];
var firstOutput = 1;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    myArray[i][j][1] = 'Output ' + firstOutput;
  }
  firstOutput = firstOutput + 1;
}

console.log(myArray);
```

However, rather than getting the desired result, what I'm actually getting is this:

```
[[['A','Output 3'],['B','Output 3']],
 [['C','Output 3'],['D','Output 3']],
 [['E','Output 3'],['F','Output 3']]]
```

So instead of getting Output 1 for the first array, Output 2 for the second an 3 for the third, I'm getting Output 3 every time.

If anyone could give me a hand in getting that result I'm looking for, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Try to run the code you posted; it does do what you want, and it does not do what you say it does.

Comment: Strangely, although I was surprised to see you're right when I tried to run the code using the exact array I posted above as an example, when I run the same code using the actual array I'm working on (which has the exacy same structure), it doesn't seem to work... This is the actual array: [[[Pessoa física, X], [Pessoa jurídica, X]], [[Pessoa física, X], [Pessoa jurídica, X]], [[Pessoa física, X], [Pessoa jurídica, X]]]

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript. Please make sure your [example] is as correct as you can make it, and reproduces your error. If I imagine you had proper JavaScript syntax there, I would be concerned that you don't have three different subarrays, but three references to the same one. The key to this problem is not what specifically is in the array, but how the array is created; you should show that code (though it is almost certain someone will find a duplicate for this, as it is a common mistake).

Comment: Here's the deal. If I copy and paste that line I just told you is the actual array and save it as a variable, the code works. It still doesn't work on the actual array, though (which was created by getting data from google forms). I was under the impression, however, that the source of the values in the array wouldn't really matter... Hmm... struggling to find out what the problem may be.

Comment: Look at the difference between `let a = [1, 2]; let b = [a, a, a]; b[0][0] = 7; console.log(JSON.stringify(b))` and `let b = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]; b[0][0] = 7; console.log(JSON.stringify(b))`. The `b` in the first one starts with three references to `[1, 2]`; the second has three _copies_ of `[1, 2]`. They might look the same, but they are structurally very different.

Comment: That's actually incredibly helpful! Makes a lot of sense - has to be the reason I'm getting this result. I created the array I'm working on by making 3 "copies" of a previous array using the Array.prototype.push.apply method. Obviously I didn't do what I meant to do. In any case, I should be able to take a step back and find the problem now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```js
var myArray = [
  [
    ['A', 'X'],
    ['B', 'X']
  ],
  [
    ['C', 'X'],
    ['D', 'X']
  ],
  [
    ['E', 'X'],
    ['F', 'X']
  ]
];

let itemIndex = 1;
var newArray = [];
myArray.map((item) => {
 var arr = [];
 item.map((elem) => {
    elem[1] = 'Output ' + itemIndex;
    arr.push(elem);
  });
  newArray.push(arr);
  itemIndex = itemIndex + 1;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Although the problem was actually the fact that my original array had been created making references and not true _copies_ of a previous array, this answer seems to be a better solution than the one I was using with nested for loops. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did with for each:

```
  var arr = [
    [["A", "X"], ["B", "X"]],
    [["C", "X"], ["D", "X"]],
    [["E", "X"], ["F", "X"]]
  ];
  var count = 1
  var newArray = []
  arr.forEach(array => {
    var a = []
    array.forEach(arr => {
      arr[1] = "Output " + count
      a.push(arr)
    })
    count++
    newArray.push(a)
  })
  console.log(newArray)
```